# OutputCache is not working if content encoding addded to header

Tags: asp.net, gzip, outputcache, deflate, content-encoding

I have a controller and an action in it.

```
public class LoginController
{
    [OutputCache(Duration = 10000, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        ......
    }
}
```

Above code is working and there is no problem with output cache. Everything is ok.

But when i added the code below to Application_BeginRequest something goes wrong. I added the picture of the page.

```
 string encodings = app.Request.Headers.Get("Accept-Encoding");
 if (encodings != null)
 {
            // Check the browser accepts deflate or gzip (deflate takes preference)
            encodings = encodings.ToLower();

            if (encodings.Contains("gzip"))
            {
                app.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(app.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
            }
            else if (encodings.Contains("deflate"))
            {
                app.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(app.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
            }

 }
```

[image: The page is ....]

Comment: Instead of  `app.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");` try `app.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "deflate");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a `VaryByContentEncoding`.
Without one, only 1 version gets cached.

If this version in the cache has been constructed from a request supporting eg. gzip compression, this cached data will be compressed in gzip format.
This same compressed data will then also be served to requests that don't support compression or only deflate, which results into what you see.

You must ensure that separate versions get cached; 1 non compressed, 1 for gizp and another for deflate.
Doing so allows that the correct version will be served according to what the webbrowser supports.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 10000, VaryByParam = "none", VaryByContentEncoding="gzip;deflate")]
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Besides the missing `VaryByContentEncoding`, there's more going on.

The `Application_BeginRequest` isn't 'playing nice' with the `OutputCacheAttribute`.
Because of this, the cache duration doesn't get applied anymore.
This must have to do with the order of execution and which headers get set at which moment.

Instead of relying on `Application_BeginRequest` move the compression code to an action filter,
which for `ASP.NET MVC` is the advised way to act within the request pipeline.
See the `CompressAttribute` below.

By means of example, I applied it to the out-of-the box `About` method on the `HomeController`.
This time, the results are as expected matching the request and response http-headers.

**CompressAttribute:**

```
public class CompressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;

        string encodings = request.Headers.Get("Accept-Encoding");
        if (encodings != null)
        {
            // Check the browser accepts deflate or gzip (deflate takes preference)
            encodings = encodings.ToLower();

            if (encodings.Contains("gzip"))
            {
                response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
            }
            else if (encodings.Contains("deflate"))
            {
                response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
                response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeController:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Compress()]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 10, VaryByParam = "none", VaryByContentEncoding="gzip;deflate")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss.fff");
        return View();
    }        
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution recommendation. When i added the code above the login page wasnt cached. I inserted a breakpoint and everytime it was hit. :((

Comment: On second thaught, you are setting up caching on **logout**; isn’t that by default implemented as a redirect instead of returning (cacheable) content? Actually even the login page is no good candidate for caching because of the antiforgery token.

Comment: @brtb You are right, with the `VaryByContentEncoding` the caching isn't being applied. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: before you submit this answer i found the solution and i have been testing it.  "The Application_BeginRequest isn't 'playing nice' with the OutputCacheAttribute" is certanly true sentence.